# Error occurred in deployment step 'Recycle IIS Application Pool': Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, deployment, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2012

I get this error in the deployment step of a share-point farm based project. Most of the suggested solutions on the net are a simple Visual Studio re-start, however, a simple VS restart won't fix this.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: I just unloaded and reloaded project then it worked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem today. I compared the project files with an older version. In my case the Package directory (with the files Package.package and Package.Template.xml) was missing.

After copying this directory back from the older version of the project and modifying the csproj file to include the references to the package directory, the error solved and the solution can be deployed again.

I added the following settings to the csproj file to restore the binding to the package directory.

```
<ItemGroup>
...
    <None Include="Package\Package.package">
      <PackageId>{03851424-152b-45c0-80c9-ac18975dc663}</PackageId>
    </None>
    <None Include="Package\Package.Template.xml">
      <DependentUpon>Package.package</DependentUpon>
    </None>
...
</ItemGroup>
```

Something similar could be the problem in your situation.

Comment: Exactly what happened to me.  In my case I opened the same Visual Studio solution on another SharePoint server, did a Get Latest through TFS but the package was missing from the project.  I had to "Get Specific Version" and overwrite all files to get the correct .csproj through.

Comment: Same thing happened with me. I did not have to add the mentioned lines to the csproj file though. I simply had to close and re-open the solution. I was using tfs when this happened like @Jay mentioned.

Comment: +1 & answer ; Wow this would have been very helpful then :/ this was such a pain

Comment: Thanks, it has solved the problem also in my situation. Btw it was caused by TFS and using more virtual machines and sharing one TFS workspace between them. 
VS didn't download Package folder from TFS, so Visual studio removed this config from csproj. 
So after creation of new TFS workspace and redownload source, Package folder was downloaded (Force getLastVersion and overwite existing files also helps...).

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions:

- Make sure your solution builds (without deployment) without errors. <kbd>F6</kbd>
- If not, check that your solution is set to build on **Any CPU**
- If not, check that you don't have logical programming errors in your solution

When the solution builds:

- Check your pre- and post- deployment steps <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- Still doesn't work? Validate your solution deployment URL
- Still doesn't work? Uninstall and remove your solution from the farm using `Uninstall-SPSolution` and `Remove-SPSolution` cmdlet. Make sure all of your features are gone from the farm with `Get-SPFeature` cmdlet

Comment: It didnt work after all of the above. I ended up just creating a new project and duplicating the web parts :/

Answer (score 0):

The other scenarios are explained here:
http://praveenbattula.blogspot.in/2013/07/error-occurred-in-deployment-step.html

Answer (score 0):

Before Sorry for my english.
If you insert only this code in csproj file manualy , always after is overrided with currently files package in you project  (but this is your problem, package folder not found) , you must add or create package to your project and then , in csproj file automaticaly writed new package guid in tag xml

But thanks for the precious direction

Answer (score -2):

In my case it solved by adding the setting for hosts file like

127.0.0.1 mysite.domain.com